# SQL in a DefaultServeMux gives errors

Tags: postgresql, rest, go

I am trying to do a REST API in Go. The query works when placed within the main handler (shows in terminal), but gives error in the browser when moved to the desired handler.

localhost:8080/ <------ Browser gives an error (not showing anything) and the terminal shows several error messages - one of them is:

> http: panic serving [::1]:51100: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

localhost:8080/getuser <---gives correct response

> Getuser

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

const (
    host     = "127.0.0.1"
    port     = 5432
    user     = "test"
    password = "pw"
    dbname   = "Test"
)

var db *sql.DB

type User struct {
    USER_ID   string
    USER_NAME  string
}

func handleRequests() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)
    http.HandleFunc("/getuser", Getuser)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT "USER_ID","USER_NAME" FROM users`)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
        return
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        user := User{}
        err := rows.Scan(&user.USER_ID, &user.USER_NAME) 
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
    }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s, %s\n", user.USER_ID, user.USER_NAME)
    }

}

func Getuser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Getuser")   // <-------------------------this works!
}

func main() {
    handleRequests()

    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=require",
        host, port, user, password, dbname)

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
  }
```

**EDIT**

The complete error list in terminal

> created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
>           /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2795 +0x27b 2018/03/23 08:36:39 http: panic serving [::1]:51390: runtime error: invalid
>   memory address or nil pointer dereference goroutine 36 [running]:
>   net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc4201d80a0)
>           /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1726 +0xd0 panic(0x1294460, 0x1471840)
>           /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:505 +0x229 database/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, 0x13277e0, 0xc42009e020, 0xc420028f01,
>   0xc4200a0218, 0xc4200a0220, 0xc4201e8b01)
>           /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1015 +0x3a database/sql.(*DB).query(0x0, 0x13277e0, 0xc42009e020, 0x12f7553,
>   0x26, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x12ec601, 0x8, ...)
>           /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1437 +0x66
>
> database/sql.(*DB).QueryContext(0x0, 0x13277e0, 0xc42009e020,
>   0x12f7553, 0x26, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10825ed, 0xc4201d0180, ...)
>           /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1419 +0xd2 database/sql.(*DB).Query(0x0, 0x12f7553, 0x26, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
>   0xc4201ec070, 0x8000000000000000, 0x0)
>           /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1433 +0x82 main.Getsign(0x13275a0, 0xc4202020e0, 0xc4201f4100)
>           /Users/sibert/go/src/main/api.go:55 +0x65 net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x1302020, 0x13275a0, 0xc4202020e0,
>   0xc4201f4100)
>           /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1947 +0x44 net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x147cc00, 0x13275a0, 0xc4202020e0,
>   0xc4201f4100)
>           /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2337 +0x130 net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc42009b2b0, 0x13275a0,
>   0xc4202020e0, 0xc4201f4100)
>           /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2694 +0xbc net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc4201d80a0, 0x13277a0, 0xc4201b4280)
>           /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1830 +0x651 created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
>           /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2795 +0x27b 2018/03/23 08:36:39 http: panic serving [::1]:51391: runtime error: invalid
>   memory address or nil pointer dereference goroutine 24 [running]:
>   net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc4200b4b40)
>           /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1726 +0xd0 panic(0x1294460, 0x1471840)
>           /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:505 +0x229 database/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, 0x13277e0, 0xc42009e020, 0xc420024501,
>   0xc4200a0318, 0xc4200a0320, 0xc420052b01)
>           /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1015 +0x3a database/sql.(*DB).query(0x0, 0x13277e0, 0xc42009e020, 0x12f7553,
>   0x26, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x12ec601, 0x8, ...)
>           /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1437 +0x66 database/sql.(*DB).QueryContext(0x0, 0x13277e0, 0xc42009e020,
>   0x12f7553, 0x26, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10825ed, 0xc420140480, ...)
>           /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1419 +0xd2 database/sql.(*DB).Query(0x0, 0x12f7553, 0x26, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
>   0xc42009eb10, 0x8000000000000000, 0x0)
>           /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1433 +0x82 main.Getsign(0x13275a0, 0xc42019e0e0, 0xc42019a300)
>           /Users/sibert/go/src/main/api.go:55 +0x65 net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x1302020, 0x13275a0, 0xc42019e0e0,
>   0xc42019a300)
>           /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1947 +0x44 net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x147cc00, 0x13275a0, 0xc42019e0e0,
>   0xc42019a300)
>           /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2337 +0x130 net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc42009b2b0, 0x13275a0,
>   0xc42019e0e0, 0xc42019a300)
>           /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2694 +0xbc net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc4200b4b40, 0x13277a0, 0xc4200a0780)
>           /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1830 +0x651 created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
>           /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2795 +0x27b

Comment: At which line the error occurs? Plus, the *error handling* part in the index function `for rows.Next()` in your code is incomplete, you may check and correct it.

Comment: Post the full errors log please. This error often occurs when you have a `nil` pointer.

Comment: @pie-oh-pah Done!

Comment: @vahdet "Plus, the error handling part in the index function for rows.Next() in your code is incomplete, you may check and correct it." Any hint?

Comment: Your global `db` is `nil`. In Go `:=` declares a new variable, therefore the `db` in your main function is a different variable from your global `db` which stays untouched. Then, your `index` handler, calling `db.Query` is calling that method on a `nil` value of the `*DB` type. Not what you want.

Comment: In main do, for example, something like: `_db, err := sql.Open(...` and then, before calling ListenAndServe do `db = _db`, note there's no `:` in front of `=`. This will set the global to what you want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are encountering is the classic case of variable shadowing.

The `:=` creates a new `db` variable that shadows your package level `db` variable. The set value of `db` only exists within the scope of your main function while your package level `db` variable remains as a nil pointer, thus when you attempt to perform a method call on `nil`, in your index handler, you get a panic.

The reason your Getuser handler works has nothing to do with the DefaultServeMux it's simply because you aren't attempting to access a member function on a nil value.

The way to fix this is within your main function to predeclare the `err` variable and change the `:=` to simple assignment `=`

```
func main() {
// ...
    var err error
    // this will now correctly set your package level variable
    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
// ...
}
```

Comment: Did you take out the if err != nil from main? You shouldn't be if you are handling all of your errors. In go, you cannot declare a variable and not do something with it. Double check to see that it is a part of another statement somewhere else